# socket io server is not responding when android emulator or Samsung S9+ are trying to connect but working fine with Kindle device

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

We are trying to create an android application for video chat using socket.io. We are using node js for the server. The server is running on a laptop. I tried to connect to the server using an Android emulator on the same laptop. But the server is not responding. I thought we shouldn't try to connect the emulator running on the same laptop where the server is running. I tried with Samsung S9+ device but the same result, the server is not responding. But interestingly when I tried to connect to the server from the Kindle device, the server is responding and printing the log. I used the same code for Emulator, S9+, and Kindle devices. Only when kindle device is trying to connect, the server is responding. Below is the code.

**Android code:**

```
String SIGNALING_URI = "http://192.168.1.101:7000"; // Laptop IP where the server is running and port 7000 where the server is listening

try {
    socket = IO.socket(SIGNALING_URI);
    socket.on(CREATEOFFER, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            createOffer = true;
            peerConnection.createOffer(sdpObserver, new MediaConstraints());
        }
    });

    socket.connect();
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Node.js (server) code:**

```
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var server = require('http').createServer().listen(7000, '0.0.0.0');
var io = socketIO.listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    console.log('new connection: ' + client.id);

    client.on('offer', function (details) {
        client.broadcast.emit('offer', details);
        console.log('offer: ' + JSON.stringify(details));
    });

    client.on('answer', function (details) {
        client.broadcast.emit('answer', details);
        console.log('answer: ' + JSON.stringify(details));
    });
    
    client.on('candidate', function (details) {
        client.broadcast.emit('candidate', details);
        console.log('candidate: ' + JSON.stringify(details));
    });

    client.broadcast.emit('createoffer', {});
});
```

Server code should print **"new connection: "** log when a client is trying to connect. But it is not printing that log when Android emulator or S9+ device are trying to connect but the log is getting printed when Kindle is trying to connect. I tried to do this using web sockets instead of using socket io. The server is responding for kindle device only even using web sockets also. Can anyone please let me know if there is anything wrong in the code or do I need to change any settings on S9+ device and emulator to make it work?

**Update 1:**

It seems I am using socket.io-client:0.8.2 version. But on the server node js, it seems I am using socket.io 2.3.0. Does it create any problems. Where I can find compatible versions of socket io for java and node.js. Just wanted to make sure that compatibility is not causing this issue.

**Update 2:**

I am able to see "new connection: " on the console multiple times with different client IDs. But these logs are not generated when I was trying to connect on Emulator or S9+ device. To make sure, I tried to print socket ID on client side after IO.socket(SIGNALING_URI) by using socket.id() which is printing null on the client side.

Comment: Which ip do you use for emulator on same pc?

Comment: Got it. Emulator will be using Laptop IP. So Emulator is not able to connect. But I couldn't understand why S9+ is not able to connect.

Comment: No. Wrong. On emulator you should use ip 10.0.2.2.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to reset the emulator IP Address?

Comment: And also it seems I am using socket.io-client:0.8.2 version. But on the server node js, it seems I am using socket.io 2.3.0. Does it create any problems?

Comment: ?????  `String SIGNALING_URI = "http://10.0.2.2:7000"`

Comment: I am able to see "new connection: " on the console multiple times with different client IDs. But these logs are not generated when I was trying to connect on Emulator or S9+ device. To make sure, I tried to print socket ID on client side after IO.socket(SIGNALING_URI) by using socket.id() which is printing null on the client side.